# Vue Component Loading Before Vuex Data Is Set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue2 component that relies on Vuex to retrieve the currently selected node (infoNode) in order to show that node's data to the user. I have a beforeCreate function that uses Axios to retrieve the top level nodes and set the 'infoNode' as the first node as shown below:

```
  async beforeCreate(){
    const info = await axios.get('/ajax/company-info')
    if(info.data){
      this.$store.dispatch("setCompanyInfo", info.data)
    }

// Function to retrieve top level node
    const topLevel = await axios.get('/ajax/get-root-contents')
    if(topLevel.data){
      this.$store.dispatch("loadTopLevel", topLevel.data)
    }
  },
```

**Below is the Vuex function to set the infoNode**

```
loadTopLevel(state,node){
      state.infoNode = node
    },
```

**Here is where I try to grab the infoNode data and display an icon from an array of valid icons**

```
<v-icon size="6em" v-if="fileIcons[infoNode.data.filetype]">{{ fileIcons[infoNode.data.filetype] }}</v-icon>
```

Now, in my component, I have a computed prop that retrieves this infoNode from the store for display. The issue that I'm having is that the frontend is throwing an error stating 'e.infoNode.Data' is undefined'.

This error is being thrown before the request is completed. After the request completes, the frontend successfully displays the infoNode since the store is updated.

Is there a way for me to set this data in the store before the component attempts to grab it? I've tried a lot of variations of beforeCreate (async and non) as well as created/mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case beforeCreate() is async so the component renders before you set data to store.
You're displaying `v-icon` if `fileIcons` have specific entry (`infoNode.data.filetype`), but at that moment `infoNode` is `undefined` or `infoNode.data` is undefined.

In **v-if** you should check if `infoNode` is not undefined and has entry you're searching for.

Something like this:

```
computed: {
  hasEntry() {
    if(infoNode && ('data' in infoNode)) return true

    return false
  }
}

//template
<v-icon size="6em" v-if="hasEntry">{{ fileIcons[infoNode.data.filetype] }}</v-icon>
```